# Serving a Vite.js React project with a FastAPI backend via Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, fastapi, vite

I have a project that uses a fastapi backend and a vite.js React front end. I currently have each dockerized as image.

Is there a way I can get fastapi to serve the vite projects static files so I don't have to have two images.

I have seen this https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/ but not sure if that's what I need or would it be like

```py
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

load_dotenv()  # take environment variables from .env.

app = FastAPI()

# serves static files from the /frontend/dist directory
app.mount("/frontend", StaticFiles(directory="frontend/dist"), name="frontend")
```

I have ran the above and got error `RuntimeError: Directory 'frontend/dist' does not exist`

I have my vite project in `frontend` I ran the vite build command which produced a `dist` folder with my static files inside. This is my current structure

```bash
.
├── README.md
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Pipfile
│   ├── Pipfile.lock
│   └── main.py
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── dist
    │   ├── assets
    │   │   ├── favicon.17e50649.svg
    │   │   ├── index.1cd49a68.js
    │   │   └── index.30ea237b.css
    │   └── index.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── postcss.config.js
    ├── src
    │   ├── App.jsx
    │   ├── favicon.svg
    │   ├── index.css
    │   ├── logo.svg
    │   └── main.jsx
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    └── vite.config.js
```

After MadsLindh suggested the change, I was able to start the fastapi server from within the backend directory but now I get

```bash
> uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/paul/Desktop/deal_query_ui/backend']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [79530] using WatchFiles
INFO:     Started server process [79532]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63011 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63012 - "GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63012 - "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:63013 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

I even tried to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/` but nothing  I get the same `{"detail":"Not Found"}`

##### Docker

I went on to then create a Dockerfile within the root

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim

EXPOSE 80

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY ./backend/Pipfile ./backend/Pipfile.lock ./
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --dev --system --deploy

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug


CMD ["uvicorn", "backend.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

When running this locally I get the error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 407, in main
    run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 575, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 479, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/./backend/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.mount("/frontend", StaticFiles(directory="../frontend/dist"), name="frontend")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/staticfiles.py", line 55, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist")
RuntimeError: Directory '../frontend/dist' does not exist
```

Which from my experience doesn't make sense to me as I could get the server up and running from within the BE directory.

Comment: `StaticFiles(directory="../frontend/dist")`? Since your FastAPI endpoint lives inside the `backend` directory?

Comment: that gives me something better than before...i now get `{"detail":"Not Found"}` when going to ` Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000` - just updated my comment

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of you are still exploring this. But have you tried the backend integration steps described in ViteJS's docs? https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html

I was in a similar boat and was able to get this working. Although I still needed to run two servers on different ports locally to get the HMR stuff working, but in prod you'd run `npm run build` and point static serve to the outDir of ViteJS.

Hope this helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34744538)